# rfComm Bluetooth connect to insulin pump

Tags: c#, bluetooth, rfcomm

I use 32feet.Net to connect to insulin pump which talks through rfComm protocol. I wrote a simple code to connect

```
   public void Listen()
    {
         server = new BluetoothListener(mUUID) { ServiceName =  "SerialLink" };
         Console.WriteLine("Start listen Devices");
         Console.WriteLine(server.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
         server.Start();
         while (true)
         { 
           using(BluetoothClient ConnectedClient = server.AcceptBluetoothClient())
            {
                //...
            }
        }

    }
```

Pump after start this code detects by windows, but windows doesn`t want to give a ConnectedClient callback, blocks it by the message asking to type pin-code. The main trick that it won`t help because after typing pin code in window message and send to pump I have to attach hello-byte and then she understands that connect is stabilized. Reading a 32feet Api I tried to use modern rfComm Api in Windows UWP, but it doesnt want to search my insulin pump. Here is the code:

```
public async void InitializeRfCommServer()
        {
            try
            {
                rfcommProvider = await 
                RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(RfcommServiceUuid));

                // Create a listener for this service and start listening
                socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
                socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

                await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString(),
                   SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

                rfcommProvider.StartAdvertising(socketListener,true);

                TextLabel.Text = "Listening for incoming connections";
                ServerInitiated = true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TextLabel.Text = e.Message;

                ServerInitiated = false;
            }
       }
```

So I am confused. May be try 32feet library in Windows 7? Or Try to correct UWP code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm with wireshark packet analyzer on windows to confirm, that search is not happening?